# Master page content not showing up in child

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I know there is something I am missing on this
But am unable to figure out that
I have this master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Mains.master.cs" Inherits="Sportsstop.Mains" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Sports Stop</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

N there is this Child page which should merge with the above master page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Mains.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sportsstop.Home" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server" >

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: @Robert Thanks for ur input, Well am very new to asp.net infact just started today! Plz correct me if am wrong, If i want to display a textbox on every page of the website, shouldn't it be included in the master page? My understanding of the master page is that it is the page that can replicate itself on every child!

Comment: Yes, but not in ContentPlaceholder, think about placeholder as a place, where the content from child page gets injected

Comment: Oh I think that answers my doubt.... Thanks for clearing that!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your textbox should be in child page, inside `ContentPlaceholder1`. I think that the one in master page is ignored.

If you want to have TextBox in master page, it cannot be inside ContentPlaceholder

Think about placeholder as a place, where the content from child page gets injected